# Unable to use the progress value in the main activity file from the xml file . Its showing unresolved references

Tags: android, kotlin

XML FILE

[image]

Main activity file

[image]

Its showing unresolved references

Comment: Avoid pasting image links to code. Instead paste it directly as text.

Comment: And please avoid telling us to do anything "asap".

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `findViewById<TextView>(R.id.progressBar)` with `findViewById<ProgressBar>(R.id.progressBar)`